# Smart watch communication with React Native application

Tags: react-native, wear-os, wearables

I need to develop an app using React Native which will get some data from **Amazfit Stratos** smart watch.

The smart watch is connected to the phone via **bluetooth** and has an application "Amazfit" where it actually gets the data that I need (i.e. step count, heart rate, etc.). After a lot of research (google and youtube), I have not encountered a way to import the data into my application. Since I haven't started making the application, there is no code to show. Can any one provide any basic solution to this problem?

My guess is (if it's possible):

1. Make my application communicate with the smart watch
2. Make my application communicate with Amazfit Android application

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Mateo, were you able to complete this. I need help related to this

Comment: Hello Saif, sorry but I was not able to complete it and I had to drop that part of the application due to the deadline. Someone mentioned there might be a Google API to do such things, so I'd advise you to check into that if it could be of any help. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge on the topic to be able to help you myself. Good luck!

Comment: No Problem, thank you for your reply

Comment: https://docs.zepp.com/docs/reference/app-json/ usually amazfit connects to the phone with the Zepp App. The Zepp App connect to google fit, so you can retrieve data from google fit, but often the pairing between zepp app and google fit does not work. I used Zepp for many years. https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit

Comment: Amazfit is not Wear OS. I don't believe it is easy to communicate between Amazfit and Android, but you can dig into their API here https://docs.zepp.com/docs/guides/architecture/arc/

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.zepp.com/docs/guides/architecture/arc/#ble

> BLE is used for communication between Device App and Side Service. The underlying BLE API is not user-friendly, so we provide the ZML tool library, which has a more complete implementation of the communication process and exposes the easy-to-use API.

- Use this.request method to send messages in Device App and onRequest to receive messages in Side Service
- Use this.call method to send messages in Side Service and onCall to receive messages in Device App

https://github.com/zepp-health/zml